# Tensorflow build fails

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I used this command:

```sh
bazel test --config opt //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow_test
```

but I get this error:

> ERROR: C:/tenserflow/tensorflow-r1.14/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/BUILD:138:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:clicenses_generate failed (Exit -1). Note: Remote connection/protocol failed with: execution failed: bash.exe failed: error executing command

- Bazel version: 0.25.0
- Tensorflow version: 1.14.0
- Python version: 3.7.9

What am I doing wrong? How can I build Tensorflow?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-windows.html). Why do you want to build Bazel? it seems you want to build Tensorflow

Comment: yes. I had Bazel 0.25.0 version. and I want to build Tensorflow